# How to remove non-ascii characters from logs?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, non-ascii-characters

I want to remove non ascii characters from Logs(json Strings) and parse them. but i see text like this before my json string starts, how can remove these kinds of string and parse my JSON String

> SEQ^F!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable^Yorg.apache.hadoop.io.Text^@^@^@^@^@^@Ã¬Ã¾NmbÃ<92>w^G6ÃÂ¹Ã³Â¯Ãl^@^@^X^E^@^@^@^H^@^@^^Â¯/Ã¢Ã«<8e>^WÃº{

Answer (score 0):

You can drop everything till `{` if that's safe so that you get the json string. I assume your log format is `"garbage{json}"`

example,

```
scala> val log = """SEQ^F!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable^Yorg.apache.hadoop.io.Text^@^@^@^@^@^@Ã¬Ã¾NmbÃ<92>w^G6ÃÂ¹Ã³Â¯Ãl^@^@^X^E^@^@^@^H^@^@^^Â¯/Ã¢Ã«<8e>^WÃº{"key1": "value1", "key2": ["1", "2"]}"""
log: String = SEQ^F!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable^Yorg.apache.hadoop.io.Text^@^@^@^@^@^@Ã¬Ã¾NmbÃ<92>w^G6ÃÂ¹Ã³Â¯Ãl^@^@^X^E^@^@^@^H^@^@^^Â¯/Ã¢Ã«<8e>^WÃº{"key1": "value1", "key2": ["1", "2"]}

scala> val extractJson = log.dropWhile(char => char != '{')
extractJson: String = {"key1": "value1", "key2": ["1", "2"]}
```

Then use any json api, Im using [circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/parsing.html) in following example,

```
scala> import io.circe.parser._
import io.circe.parser._

scala> parse(extractJson)
res3: Either[io.circe.ParsingFailure,io.circe.Json] =
Right({
  "key1" : "value1",
  "key2" : [
    "1",
    "2"
  ]
})
```

If you want to extract any particular element json,

```
scala> res3.map(j => (j \\ "key1").headOption)
res4: scala.util.Either[io.circe.ParsingFailure,Option[io.circe.Json]] = Right(Some("value1"))
```

Comment: If i want to parse all the key value pairs regardless of a particular elements. how do i do it.?

Comment: do you just want the json value as string? if so see my first example where you drop anything before `{` should be enough. It would be better if you can describe what you want to do with json.

Comment: I have a json and i want to flatten it out and store in a database. How can i traverse and flatten it and save